# Creating global Class holder

Tags: java, android

Hey all I am wondering how I can have a generic call to one of my classes so that I can minimize my code.

Currently I have a at of if else code that determines which class should be loaded up.

As an example in my MainActivity:

```
if (btnName.equals("up"))
    if (globalRoom.equals("ABC")) { 
        btnNumber = 0; 
        ABC.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_up", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("NBC")) { 
        btnNumber = 1;
        NBC.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_up", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("CBS")) { 
        btnNumber = 2;
        CBS.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_up", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("REK")) { 
        btnNumber = 3;
        REK.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_up", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("DSR")) { 
        btnNumber = 4;
        DSR.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_up", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("LR2")) { 
        btnNumber = 0;
        LR2.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_up", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
} else if (btnName.equals("down"))
    if (globalRoom.equals("ABC")) { 
        btnNumber = 0; 
        ABC.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_down", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("NBC")) { 
        btnNumber = 1;
        NBC.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_down", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("CBS")) { 
        btnNumber = 2;
        CBS.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_down", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("REK")) { 
        btnNumber = 3;
        REK.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_down", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("DSR")) { 
        btnNumber = 4;
        DSR.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_down", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
    else if (globalRoom.equals("LR2")) { 
        btnNumber = 0;
        LR2.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_down", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
    }
} etc etc....
```

In each of my classes ABC.java class:

```
public class ABC {
    public static void sendTheCmd(String theCmd, String TV, List<ThemedButton> all_TvType, btnNumber, Boolean keyboard) {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

NBC.java class:

```
public class NBC {
    public static void sendTheCmd(String theCmd, String TV, List<ThemedButton> all_TvType, btnNumber, Boolean keyboard) {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So instead of having all those if/else I would like to make a variable that holds any of those classes (ABC, NBC, CBS, etc...) so that I can do something like this instead:

```
GlobalClass GC;

     if (globalRoom.equals("ABC")) { btnNumber = 0; GC = new ABC(); }
else if (globalRoom.equals("NBC")) { btnNumber = 1; GC = new NBC(); }
else if (globalRoom.equals("CBS")) { btnNumber = 2; GC = new CBS(); }
else if (globalRoom.equals("REK")) { btnNumber = 3; GC = new REK(); }
else if (globalRoom.equals("DSR")) { btnNumber = 4; GC = new DSR(); }
else if (globalRoom.equals("LR2")) { btnNumber = 0; GC = new LR2(); }

if (btnName.equals("up")) {
    GC.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_up", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
} else if (btnName.equals("down")) {
    GC.sendTheCmd("?action=volume_down", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
} else if (btnName.equals("Keyboard")) {
    GC.sendTheCmd("text?", globalTV, all_TvType, btnNumber, false);
} else if (btnName.equals("Other")) {
    //Not sure what to make this icon
}
```

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
List<String, Class<?>> GC;
```

Then populate it like this:

```
GC.put("ABC", new ABC());
GC.put("NBC", new NBC());
GC.put("CBS", new CBS());
GC.put("REK", new REK());
GC.put("DSR", new DSR());
GC.put("LR2", new LR2());
```

But that does not seem to work as I was expecting it to.

Is there any way of doing this?